# Proof related to the relationship between Images and Kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> If $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix, is the formula
>   $$\operatorname{im}(A) = \operatorname{im}(AA^T)$$
>   necessarily true? Explain.

For this problem the answer says that the above will not necessarily be the same, as they are different dimensions. This makes sense to me on an intuitive level, however I am slightly confused, as we are given the theorem:

$$ Ker(A) = Ker(A^{t} A) $$

So when I originally did the problem, I did:

$$ Im(A) = Im(A^{t} A) $$

$$ Ker(A)^{PERP} = Ker(A^{t} A)^{PERP} $$

$$ (Ker(A)^{PERP})^{PERP} = (Ker(A^{t} A)^{PERP})^{PERP} $$

$$ Ker(A) = Ker(A^{t} A) $$

Which we know to be true. What exactly is wrong with this solution?

Comment: $A^TA \neq AA^T$

Comment: oh wow, thanks! That was silly @inquisitive

Answer (score 0):

This thing always holds:
$$
im(AA^T) = \ker(AA^T)^\perp = \ker(A^T)^\perp = im(A).
$$
Here, I used that $\ker(B)^\perp = im(B^T)$.